# comparing two arrays to create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This seems like a very straightforward problem but for the life of me, I can not get it sorted.

I want to compare two arrays and if the value of array2 is in array1 push it to a new array otherwise push a 0.

these are my arrays:

```
let arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
let arrayTwo = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
```

desired outcome is

```
[0,0,3,4,5,0,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,0,0]
```

current attempt with obvious indices issues

```
let newArray = [];

for (let i=0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
  if(arrayTwo.includes(i)) newArray.push(arrayTwo[i]);
  else newArray.push(0);
};
```

current result

```
[0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 13, 14, 15, 16, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0]
```

Comment: 6 and 7 are not included in arrayTwo. Why isn't the desired output `[0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 9` etc?

Comment: You check for index not for value in `arrayTwo.includes(i)` where `i` is the index try `if (arrayTwo.includes(arrayOne[i])) newArray.push(arrayOne[i]);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are correct typo'd the desired array, it's corrected. thx @Fabio checking for `includes(arrayOne[i]` gives a similar result `[0, 0, 5, 8, 9, 0, 0, 13, 14, 15, 0, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your approach is that you are searching for an index in arrayTwo

```
if(arrayTwo.includes(i)) newArray.push(arrayTwo[i]);
```

where `i` is the index not a value. That's why you are getting `undefined` values, because `arrayTwo` has less values then arrayOne, so index of arrayOne will not exists in arrayTwo.

Instead you should search for value in arrayTwo

```
for (let i=0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
  let value = arrayOne[i];
  if(arrayTwo.includes(value)) newArray.push(value);
  else newArray.push(0);
};
```

If you check only for existence of the value in collection - use `Set` which designed exactly for this purpose.

```
let arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
let values = new Set([3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);

const result = arrayOne.map(value => values.has(value) ? value : 0);
// => [0,0,3,4,5,0,0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,0,0]
```